# How does Apache Kafka Stream / KSQL handle out of order / late messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

As far as I know the kafka stream handles late messages by retention window for tolerate lag, for example

```
TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2))
                   .until(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1) /* keep for one day */)
```

1. but I can't find related parts in [KSQL](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/v0.5/docs/syntax-reference.md#syntax-reference), not support yet?
2. Can I do accurate statistics by kafka stream **WITHOUT** giving max tolerate lag (as I am not sure that)? just like Apache Flink [sideOutputLateData](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#getting-late-data-as-a-side-output) to handle late messages specially.

Answer (score 2):

KSQL uses Kafka Streams so at the moment the retention policy for window is 1 day. Currently you cannot configure this in the syntax but it can be added to the window syntax. I would encourage you to add an feature request (GitHub issue) in the KSQL repository (https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql) for this.